# How to measure framerate programatically in react native

Tags: react-native, performance-testing

I want to improve the performance of my React Native app, because the UI is janky in certain situations.

I have a few ideas, however, to determine if they work or not I need to **measure them**

I'd like to write a test that measures the framerate over time in a number of different scenarios, so I can compare the performance before and after implementing different ideas.

The React Native devtools does include an framerate measurement widget - but is there any way I can access this information programatically, and record/sample it over time?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, did you get any idea on how to measure the frame rate ?

Comment: @AbinMDevasia I found the android-only systrace tool the most helpful in the end - see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#1-collecting-a-trace.  It was quite easy to use, and gives a chart showing the 16ms frame boundaries and the work involved in rendering each frame, and late frames are highlighted